# JSONArray with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this web service where I display a JSONobject, and I want to display to a JSONArray in the begening like this example :
http://mbmsam.byethost7.com/employes.json

How to do it please ?

This is my code

```
<?php

require_once 'include/config.php';

mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from doctor");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $output[]=$row;

}
//$array = json_decode(true);
$array = array('doctor' => $output);
echo  json_encode($array) ;  
mysql_close();

?>
```

EDIT : I added my solution.

Comment: What is your problem ? at the moment your code is fine.. it should work.. (you dont need the $array = line and perhaps you must define $output=array(); before the while and its good after your echo to set exit(); no other code must be send..)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the elements you want to save in your array. in this case, if you want to save into an array the values 'name' and 'last_name', the code would look like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/config.php';

mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from contacts");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $array = array('name' => $row['name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name']);

}

echo  json_encode($array);  
mysql_close();

?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php

require_once 'include/config.php';

mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from contacts");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $array[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name']);

}

echo  json_encode($array);  
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Your `$array` would only contain the last item. I think you meant `$array[] =` instead?

Comment: I would like to display the table name first, not the last item.

Comment: @BlidTounsi: What **exactly** is the issue with the code in your question?

Comment: I fixed the problem and I edited my code. In fact, I would like to just display the title of the table ^^ Thanks every body for your contribution.